# Obtener polinomio opuesto

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Se que puede ser una tontería pero no encuentro cómo hacerlo. Quiero saber cómo puedo calcular el polinomio opuesto creado en Numpy **independientemente de su grado**.

Ejemplo que no me funciona:

```
import numpy as np


p0 = np.poly1d([2., 0., 0., -100., 2., -1.])
p1 = np.polyder(p0, 1)
p2 = -1. @ (np.polydiv(p0, p1))[1]
p3 = -1. @ np.polydiv(p1, p2[1])[1]
p4 = -1. @ np.polydiv(p2[1], p3[1])[1]
print(p0)
print(p1)
print(p2[1])
print(p3[1])
print(p4[1])
```

La salida es la siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-9-9aab292f9c1e> in <module>()
      1 p0 = np.poly1d([2., 0., 0., -100., 2., -1.])
      2 p1 = np.polyder(p0, 1)
----> 3 p2 = -1. @ (np.polydiv(p0, p1))[1]
      4 p3 = -1. @ np.polydiv(p1, p2[1])[1]
      5 p4 = -1. @ np.polydiv(p2[1], p3[1])[1]

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for @: 'float' and 'poly1d'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplemente multiplica por -1.

El operador @, que utilizas en el ejemplo, es para multiplicación entre matrices y por eso el error `TypeError` de que no soporta esa operación.

```
import numpy as np

p0 = np.poly1d([2., 0., 0., -100., 2., -1.]) 
print(p0)
       5       2
2 x - 100 x + 2 x - 1

#polinomio opuesto de p0
p0_opuesto = p0 * -1
print(p0_opuesto)
    5     4     3       2
-2 x - 0 x - 0 x + 100 x - 2 x + 1
```

Comment: Antes también intenté p2 = -(np.polydiv(p0, p1))[1] pero no funciona. Me ha funcionado haciendo p2 = (np.polydiv(p0, p1))[1] , p2 = -p2

Comment: @Tobal No te funciona porque debe ser así `p2 = -(np.polydiv(p0, p1)[1])`, fíjate que el paréntesis debe estar al final. Así como en las matemáticas la operación dentro de los paréntesis tiene prioridad.

Comment: es que en mates en situaciones así no pongo los paréntesis por ser rediundantes, cosas de la programación. Muchas gracias